# Weird Output in the Main Method

Tags: arrays, numbers

I need to generate 5 + 1 UNIQUE random numbers and store them into array which is then returned. Here's my code

```
public static int[] drawNumbers(int number)
{
    int[] unique = new int[7];
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    while(x < unique.length)
    {
        unique[x] = (int)(Math.random()*45+1);

        while(y < x)
        {
            if(unique[x] == unique[y])
            {
                x--;
                break;
            }
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return unique;
}
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code but when I do this in the main method:

```
System.out.print(drawNumbers(parameter) + " ");
```

I get outputs like this:
" [I@4a5e88f7 "

Answer (score 0):

`drawNumbers` returns an array of integers, but `System.out.print` can't print out an entire array. Instead, you need to print each item seperately, like so:

```
for (int x : drawNumbers(parameter)) {
    System.out.print(x + " ");
}
```

Comment: Hey dude, I hope you don't mind me asking it here, because I can't really find what I'm looking for but..

How do I pass a multi-dimentional array onto another method? Say I have "numbers[x][y]". How do I pass this to method "checkNumber()"?